# How to post null values in JSONSerialization parameters if some of the variables are nil in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsurlsession, nsjsonserialization

my code looks like this. I've around 10 parameters and some of the values can be nil and if the values are nil, I need to http post those nil values as null.

```
func someFunc(userId: Int, param1: String?, param2: String?, param3: String?, completion: @escaping (_ response: [String: Any]) -> Void) {

        let url = URL(string: "api-endpoint")
        let parameters: [String: Any] = ["id": userId, "param1": param1, "param2": param2, "param3": param3] //here's the params can be nil.
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else {
            return
        }
   request.httpBody = httpBody
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
                    completion(json)
                } catch let err {
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: does "" works equals to null or just null what is required.

Comment: I need to send null to the server if the variables are nil. And if not nil, then the values of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    func someFunc(userId: Int, param1: String?, param2: String?, param3: String?, completion: @escaping (_ response: [String: Any]) -> Void) {

        let url = URL(string: "api-endpoint")
        let parameters: [String: Any] = ["id": userId ?? "null", "param1": param1 ?? NSNull, "param2": param2 ?? NSNUll, "param3": param3 ?? NSNull] //here's the params can be nil.
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else {
            return
        }
   request.httpBody = httpBody
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
                    completion(json)
                } catch let err {
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: "null" is getting stored as String. I need to set NSNull() if nil.. but not getting how to set.

Comment: what error is given in swift compiler or backend is throwing error